# How to pass XML to C# API function using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, xml, web-services

Below is the method in my API. Can someone tell me how to format data to send to this method using a GET request made through jQuery? It accepts data in XML format and returns a result in XML format. Can any one help me to format the array or data that I need to send to this method.

```
public List<VwSale_Rpt> InsertSaleEntry(VwSale sale, List<VwSaleItem> saleItem)
{
    return SaleUtils.InsertSaleRecord(sale, saleItem);
}
```

It accepts data in this XML format:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <InsertSaleEntry xmlns="http://LuckyYantra/SaleServices/">
            <sale>
                <SaleId>int</SaleId>
                <UserId>int</UserId>
                <Date>dateTime</Date>
                <DrawTimeIntervalId>int</DrawTimeIntervalId>
                <CouponNo>string</CouponNo>
                <Qty>int</Qty>
                <Amount>int</Amount>
                <ActualAmount>double</ActualAmount>
                <IsCancel>int</IsCancel>
                <CancelDate>dateTime</CancelDate>
                <CancelBy>int</CancelBy>
            </sale>
            <saleItem>
                <VwSaleItem>
                    <SaleItemId>int</SaleItemId>
                    <SaleId>int</SaleId>
                    <ItemId>int</ItemId>
                    <Rate>int</Rate>
                    <ActualRate>double</ActualRate>
                    <Qty>int</Qty>
                    <Amount>int</Amount>
                    <ActualAmount>double</ActualAmount>
                </VwSaleItem>
                <VwSaleItem>
                    <SaleItemId>int</SaleItemId>
                    <SaleId>int</SaleId>
                    <ItemId>int</ItemId>
                    <Rate>int</Rate>
                    <ActualRate>double</ActualRate>
                    <Qty>int</Qty>
                    <Amount>int</Amount>
                    <ActualAmount>double</ActualAmount>
                </VwSaleItem>
            </saleItem>
        </InsertSaleEntry>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the c# XML parser? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: $.ajax({
              url: '<url to api >',
              data: { userId: userid,password: password },
              method: 'post',
              dataType: 'xml',
              success: function (data) {
               var $xmlDoc = jQuery(data);
               var UserLoginresult=$xmlDoc.find('UserLoginResult').text();
    }

Comment: i was passing just like this but i am having problem as it needs list as a parameter